# JSON Chrome Extension Problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a google chrome extension as a project and have run into a hurdle. I am playing around with JSON (hoping to eventually use an API i like). I have an example JSON file, load it, get a variable storing the parsed JSON (which I can see as an object, containing objects and values), however, I don't know how to reference values of the objects within.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp;
xhr.open("GET", "eg.json", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

The object resp looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6kp9.png) after send is executed.

I guess this is because I'm new to JavaScript but how would I get the createdDate as a String variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access it via [dot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) or [bracket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) (more for dynamic properties) notation (or a mix of both) like any other nested objects.  For example, based on the image you posted it would be:

```
var createdDate = resp.WhoisRecord.audit.createdDate;
```

Note you need to call this inside that `if` where `resp` is defined, only in that callback will it be populated...if you try and use it *after* your `xhr.onreadystatechange =` function hookup, it won't be ready *when it runs*, inside that callback with a `readyState == 4`, it should be.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I had that line correct gladly and it appears you have found my real problem, getting a variable out of that function. How would I go about this since I can't see a way to access its return?